# Wird ein Satz auch dann mit einem Großbuchstaben begonnen, wenn das erste Wort in Anführungsstrichen steht?

Tags: english-to-german, capitalization

Wir betrachten diesen Satz:

> "Ambitious" ist ein englisches Wort und bedeutet soviel wie "ehrgeizig".

Ist der Satz so richtig? Was mich wundert, ist, dass "ambitious" als Adjektiv ja eher kleingeschrieben werden sollte, aber der deutsche Satz ja trotzdem mit einem Großbuchstaben beginnen sollte.

Comment: Please see the above.